# How do I create a sequence of dates?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to count the number of actions per day in my dataset.

```
date         action_id
2010-01-01   id00
2010-01-03   id01
2010-01-05   id02
```

This is just a sample, but the point is that my data does not include actions for every day and I want to include days where there are zero actions in my result.

My plan is to do this.

```
with dates as (
select [sequence of dates from 2010-01-01 to 2010-02-01] as day)

select day, coalesce(count(distinct action_id), 0) as actions
from dates
left join my_table
on dates.date = my_table.date
```

How do I create the sequence of dates?

Comment: You can create a date table with all the dates in it and join to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You example shows a CTE.  So, you can use a recursive CTE:

```
with recursive dates as (
      select date('2010-01-01') as day
      union all
      select day + interval 1 day
      from dates
      where day < '2010-02-01'
     )
select d.day, count(distinct t.action_id) as actions
from dates d left join
     my_table t
     on d.day = my_table.date
group by d.day;
```

Note that `COUNT()` never returns `NULL`, so `COALESCE()` is unnecessary.

In older versions, you can use a calendar table or generate the data on the fly.  Assuming your table has enough rows:

```
select d.day, count(distinct t.action_id) as actions
from (select date('2010-01-01') + interval (@rn := @rn + 1) - 1 day as day
  from my_table cross join
       (select @rn := 0) params
  limit 31
 ) d left join
     my_table t
     on d.day = my_table.date
group by d.day;
```

Comment: How do I make the common table expression recursive? It can't find the `dte` object

Comment: @tadon11Aaa . . . The simpler solution is to fix the typo -- which I just did.

Comment: Is recursive a category of common table expressions?

Comment: @tadon11Aaa . . . Yes it is:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions-recursive.

Answer (score 0):

it seems just you need group by and count

```
 select date, count(distinct action_id) as action
 from my_table left join
 dates on dates.date = my_table.date
  group by date
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with dates as
(
select a.Date 
from (
    select curdate() - INTERVAL (a.a + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a) + (1000 * d.a) ) DAY as Date
    from (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as a
    cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as b
    cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as c
    cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as d
) a
where a.Date between '<start_date>' and '<end_date>' )
select day, count(distinct action_id) as actions
from dates
left join my_table
on dates.date = my_table.date
```